# Find and show information from logs inside a folder in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a little script using bash in linux. That allows me to find if there is any tag 103=16 inside a log

I have multiple folders named for example l51prdsrv-api1.nebex.local, l51prdsrv-oe1.nebex.local, etc... inside those folders are .log files like TRADX_gsoe3.log, TRADX_gseuoe2.log, etc... .

I need to find if inside those logs there is the tag 103=16

I'm trying this command

find .  /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "*TRADX_*" -type f | grep -e 103=16

But what it does is that is showing just the logs names and not the content to see if there is a tag 103=16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not searching files of the form `TRADX_something.log`, but only files which are just named `TRADX_` (case-insensitively, so `TradX_` would also be found).

Then you are feeding to `grep` the names of the files, but never look into the content of those files. From the `grep` man page, you see that the file content can be supplied either via stdin, or by specifying the file name on the command line. In your case, the latter is the way to go. Therefore you can either do a

```
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_*.log" -type f -exec grep -F 103=16 {} \;
```

if you are only interested in the matchin lines, or a

```
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_*.log" -type f -exec grep -F 103=16 {} /dev/null \;
```

if you also want to see the file names where the pattern matches. The reason is that `grep` is printing the filename only if it sees more than 1 filename on the command line and the /dev/null provides a second dummy file. *find* replaces the `{}` by the filename.

BTW, I used `-f` for *grep* instead of your `-e`, because you don't seem to use any specific regular expression pattern anyway.

But you don't need `find` for this task. An alternative would be an explicit loop:

```
shopt -s nocasematch # make globbing case-insensitive
shopt -s globstar # turn on ** globbing
for f in {.,/opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv*}/**/tradx_*.log
do
  [[ -f $f ]] && grep -F 103=16 "$f" /dev/null
done
```

While the loop looks more complicated at first glance, it is easier to extend the logic in case you want to do more with the files instead of just grepping the lines, for instance taking specific actions on those files which contain the pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes you are right as well with the -f, lets see if i can get it done with it!

Comment: The code find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_*.log" -type f -exec grep -f 103=16 {} /dev/null \;  did give me a result: "grep: 103=16: No such file or directory" . But when i look for the tag inside one of the logs, for example the TRADX_bnpdc1.log doing a cat -A TRADX_bnpdc1.log | grep 103=16. I do find there is a tag 103=16. Don't know why is not finding it

Comment: Sorry, my typo. Must be `-F` of course, not `-f`. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_" -type f | grep -e 103=16
```

I propose you do:

```
find . /opt/FIXLOGS/l51prdsrv* -iname "TRADX_" -type f -exec grep -e "103=16" {} /dev/null \;
```

What's the difference?

```
find ... -type f
```

=> gives you a list of files.

When you add `| grep -e 103=16`, then you perform that on the filenames.
When you add `-exec grep ...`, then you perform that on the files itselfs.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! i will try it. Hopefully this will do the trick!